# Show/Hide Div based on dynamic value in span

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, show-hide

I have a span that contains a number which is the sum of the total number of checkboxes checked in a quiz. I need to hide and show 2 different divs based on the number value of that span. This is the code I have which effectively hides the divs but is not showing them. Help!

```
<div class="results center">
    Your Score Is: <span class="yes_results">0</span> 
</div>
<div id="less">less div</div>
<div id="more">more div</div>
```

The score (span value) is calculated by the following code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.yes').change(function(){
        var yes = $('.yes:checked').length;
        var no = $('.no:checked').length;
        $('.yes_results').text(yes);
        $('.no_results').text(no);                     
    })
});
```

And the code that I have that is currently hiding but not showing the divs is this

```
$(function() {
    var x = $("span.yes_results").text();

    if (x == 0){
         $("div#less").hide();
         $("div#more").hide();
    }
    else if ((x > 0) && (x < 4)) {
         $("div#less").show(); 
         $("div#more").hide();
    }
    else if (x > 3) {
         $("div#less").hide(); 
         $("div#more").show();
    };
});
```

Comment: Please show the complete code that works as you describe it so far.

Comment: I think your issue is that you're comparing string to ints. Try using .parseInt() on your strings when you are comparing them to an integer.

Comment: Not clear what your question is here. Are you not getting the proper value on x or is it something else? BTW your 2nd else contradicts with the 1st else. You see only when x >= 4 the last else will be triggered.

Comment: It looks like your show/hide function only runs once when the document is ready. You need to have this function hooked into some event that will occur as the page is interacted with.

Comment: @P.K. I am getting the proper value on x, but the divs are not being displayed. Just hidden.

Comment: It will always be 0 here since it's hard coded to be so, thus hide the #less and #more divs just as your code tells it to. Are you wanting user interaction here? If so, that should probably be an input hooked up to an onchange event, etc. console.log for debugging is your friend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I stated in the comments, your show/hide function is being registered as a callback function for when the document is ready (which only happens once so your function doesn't run again), but you need it to run whenever the span's value changes, so you'll need it connected to that event.

You also are comparing the string results of the `.text()` method return value against a number, so you need to convert that.

A simple solution would be to combine the functions:

```
$(function() {
    $('.yes').change(function(){
        var yes = $('.yes:checked').length
        var no = $('.no:checked').length 
        $('.yes_results').text(yes)
        $('.no_results').text(no) 
        showHide();  // Now, update the display based on the span                     
    });

    showHide();  // Now, update the display based on the span

});


function showHide(){

    // The text() method will return a string, so you need to 
    // convert it to a number to be able to compare it to a number
    var x = parseInt($("span.yes_results").text(),10);

    if (x == 0){
         $("div#less").hide();
         $("div#more").hide();
     } else if ((x > 0) && (x < 4)) {
         $("div#less").show(); 
         $("div#more").hide();
     } else if (x > 3) {
         $("div#less").hide(); 
         $("div#more").show();
     };

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the following code to parse the string value to integer.

```
var x = parseInt($("span.yes_results").text());
```